# Questions about V(XY) , X and Y are independent

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

[image]

[image]

I don't really understand the part [image: V(S)=(E(N))(V(X))+(V(N))(E(X))^2]

How is the formula be derived? Isn't V(S)=(E(N^2))(E((X^2))−(E(N)(E(X))^2 as X and N are independent?

Comment: Please edit your post, using math markup ($\LaTeX$), si it will be easier to read. And consider adding some context, if this is self-study, add that tag.

Comment: Hint: Do you know the double expectation theorem, that $E E [X|Y] = E X$?  if not, learnt it, use it!

Comment: Thanks for the hint , which part of the questions indicate that the usage of double expectation? Thank you

Comment: See http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml . A slightly neater approach is to use probability generating functions.  (This still uses $\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = \mathbb{E}X$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight variation on the proof in the link I posted:

Denote the PGF of a random variable $Z$ by $P_Z(t) := \mathbb{E}[t^Z]$.  Note that $P''_Z(1) = \mathbb{E}[Z(Z-1)]$.

By the result that @kjetil b halvorsen gave, we have
$P_S(t) = P_N(P_X(t))$.  Differentiating twice gives
$$
P''_S(t) = P''_N(P_X(t))(P'_X(t))^2 + P'_N(P_X(t))P''_X(t)
$$

Thus,
$$
Var[S] = \mathbb{E}[S(S-1)] + \mathbb{E}[S] - \mathbb{E}[S]^2 
  \\ =  P''_N(1)(P'_X(1))^2 + P'_N(1)P''_X(1) + \mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X] - (\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X])^2
\\ = \mathbb{E}[N(N-1)]\mathbb{E}[X]^2 + \mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] + \mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X] - (\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X])^2
$$
which gives the the answer.